# Screen size method fails in android

Tags: android, size, screen

I am attempting to use different layout schemes for my app given if the device is a large screen or not.  right now I am only supporting a large screen and below, and anything that is smaller than "large" is defined by just the regular "layout" folder.  I am doing some logic checking below:

```
        MainMenuFragment mmFrag = new MainMenuFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();           

        if(isLarge()){

            transaction.add(R.id.main_menu_frame, mmFrag, "MainMenuFragment");
        }

        else{

            transaction.add(R.id.testframe, mmFrag, "MainMenuFragment");
        }

        transaction.commit();
```

However the condition is always returning false from this method.  I have confirmed this by changing the else condition to the same as if statement and the program will work.  Otherwise it crashes (correctly) due to no layout file in testframe:

```
        public boolean isLarge() {

        if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
                Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Am I missing something in isLarge()?

Comment: Rather than doing like this, add support screens in manifest and let android do the rest i.e use layout from different layout folders.

Comment: Oh I should mention that the tablet I am using to test this is large.  10.1 note.

Comment: I am using different layout folders however the problem arises when I have a smaller screen, I have one layout active.  If I have a large screen I have 2 layouts active.  If the code tries to load one fragment, it will not know what to do with the other fragment.  So my set up has a little error handling to counter this.

Comment: Do you want to calculate the screensize of the device when in any orientation ?

Comment: I have orientation covered with layout profiles.  I just need to know why this method isn't working.

Comment: It is working for me. Checked on device with size 10, 7 and 4.